# Monopoly Golden Token Bonus release date?

Tags: monopoly

In 2013, Hasbro dropped the Iron piece from Monopoly and added a new Cat. Alongside this announcement, they were going to [release a "Monopoly Golden Token Bonus" board that would have all the old pieces and the 5 new pieces that were up for voting](https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/2013/01/08/monopoly-board-game-tokens-change/1805387/), and that this would be released as a Target exclusive in mid-February 2013. As of that date, it doesn't seem to be available in stores or online.

What was the official release date for the board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 'reviews section' on the linked target website:

> I spoke with customer service at Hasbro on 2-8-13 and was told the
>   release date is March 1st, 2013. It is a Target promotion and will not
>   be available anywhere else.

http://www.target.com/p/monopoly-golden-token-bonus/-/A-14428620

However, the same website says that the release date was:

> Release Date: February 5, 2013

So, they are possibly sold out.

An Ebay search reveals a number of people selling this version of the game along with the special edition tokens, so it furthers the theory that the game was released and is sold out.

--edit--

It looks like the target has gotten more in stock. Not sure how long it will last though.

Comment: I'm 95% sure it was released and sold out. I just can't find the actually article. Every eBay auction mentions that it was a Target online exclusive and is sold out. Plus there are a few stories about shipping, most notably on the Target website product page for the Monopoly Golden Token Edition.

Comment: @SocioMatt do you think that Target will even get more in?

Comment: I doubt it, although there's no empirical evidence to back that claim up. I'd guess they were taking a loss on each one. Having said that, Target has normal Monopoly listed at $11.99, and other -opolies fall around $25, so who knows what the profit margin is. My guess is it isn't big enough to continue to produce more. Unfortunately (and stupidly, because what kind of jerk buys a board game to resell it on eBay for 6 times the original cost?), your best option may be to try and get it online through eBay or Amazon. It might be worth calling Hasbro again to see if more are being shipped.

Comment: @RobAveryIV Contacting either/both Hasbro or Target seems like the best solution here.

Answer (score 3):

Target has them in stock - just keep checking their website as it alternates between available and not available.